# How do I add a class to a specific input type?

Tags: 8, theming

Using Drupal 8. I am trying to add `class="input"` to an `input` with `type="text"`; any other type (i.e `type="button"`) should not have that class added. I modified `input.html.twig` to the following:

```
<input{{ attributes.addClass('input') }}/>{{ children }}
```

The problem with this is that it adds the class to all input types. Is there a way to specify the input type in which the class should be added in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template files are available by default for each input type.

- Copy the input.html.twig file and rename it input--textfield.html.twig
- Put it in the folder of the theme
- Clear the cache and the new template will be used for all text-field form fields
- You can add `<input{{ attributes.addClass('input') }}/>{{ children }}` in that file

If you want a more customized input field, you implement [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK/8.6.x).

```
function YOUR_THEME_NAME_theme_suggestions_input_alter(array &$suggestions, array $variables) {
  // To see available variables use kint().
  kint($variables);
  if ($variables['element']['#type'] == 'textfield' && $variables['element']['#name'] == field__--------- ) {
    $suggestions[] = 'input__customized';
  }
}
```